# dynamic creation of textbox

Tags: dom

while i create textbox dynamically i can able to add any no
of textbox while i delete only last textbox got deleted after it 
an throws exception.

```
<html>
  <head>My page </html>
     <body>
         <div id="firstdiv">   
         <input type="text" id="text" id="text1" value=""/>
         <input type="button" id="butt" name="it's okay" value="+" onclick="text_add()"/>
         <input type="button" id="butt1" name="it's okay" value="-" nclick="text_remove()"/>
         </div>
     </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
function text_add()
{
   ++i;
  var bal=document.createElement("input")
      bal.setAttribute("type","text");
      bal.setAttribute("id","text"+i);
      bal.setAttribute("name","bala");
      firstdiv.appendChild(bal);

}
function text_remove()
{
try{
  var a="\"";
  a+="text"+(i);
  a+="\"";
    alert(a);
  var bal=document.getElementById(a);
  firstdiv.removeChild(bal);
   --i;
}catch(e)
  {
   alert("Echo"+e);
   }
}
</script>
</html>
```

chorme throws error: after deleting one text box like 
**EchoError: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you whant to add and remove textboxes.
and the latest textbox added shuld be removed?

so first you alreddy have a textbox in the dom witch will colide with your
naming

```
<input type="text" id="text" id="text1" value=""/>
```

is this an atemt to manualy add qoutes ? becus thats not part of the id
of the element

```
var a="\"";
a+="text"+(i);
a+="\"";
```

just give it the name normaly

```
var bal = document.getElementById("text" + i);
```

and you dont have to mess around with dom ids you can store
dom elements as normal objects so
something like this works fine

```
 var textElements = [];
 var firstdiv = document.getElementById("firstdiv");
 function text_add() {
   var bal = document.createElement("input");
   bal.setAttribute("type","text");
   bal.setAttribute("name","bala");
   firstdiv.appendChild(bal);
   textElements.push(bal);
 }
 function text_remove() {
   firstdiv.removeChild(textElements.pop());
 }
```

the pop method removes the last added item in the array

Comment: u leave id  bal.setAttribute("id","text"+textElements.push()); now it's working fine. but i want to know about reason for error occur in my code. simply i want know bug in my code.

Comment: first of all this line var bal=document.getElementById("text1"); is not taking the last element it gets the same element every time... i asume this code var a="\"";
  a+="text"+(i);
  a+="\""; is an atemt to generate the last id to use like this bal=document.getElementById(a) .... but you dont need the qoutes youst do this bal=document.getElementById("text" + i) .. then the code works